# Create a function that takes a structure (or a pointer to the structure) as parameter and sorts the names in alphabetical order

Tags: c, function, sorting, struct, c-strings

I create a structure with 3 names,and I want to create a function that takes a structure (or a pointer to the structure) as parameter and sorts the names in alphabetical order. I don't know how to fix the `sort_name` function, can anyone give me tips? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {

    char name[50];

};

void getDetail(struct student *ptr) {

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    printf("Enter %dth name: " ,i+1);
    scanf("%s", ptr->name);
    ptr++;
  }
}

void sort_name(struct student *ptr) {

   int i,j=0;
   char temp[50];
   for (i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       for (j=i+1;j<3;j++)
       {
           if(strcmp(ptr->name,(ptr+1)->name)>0)
           {
               strcpy(temp,ptr->name);
               strcpy(ptr->name,(ptr+1)->name);
               strcpy((ptr+1)->name,temp);
           }

       }


   }

   printf("In order:");
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       printf("%s",ptr->name);
   }

}

int main()
{
    struct student s[3];
    getDetail(s);
    sort_name(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless it's an assignment requirement that you implement your own sorting, then *don't*. Use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) instead.

Comment: For your current code, note that `ptr->name` is equal to `ptr[0].name`, and `(ptr + 1)->name` is equal to `ptr[1].name`. Now in the sorting loops is there anything that will make `ptr` point somewhere else or for you to use any other index? And I really recommend you use array-indexing syntax instead of using the pointers.

Comment: Related, for a fixed three element array you don't even need a function or a loop. A three step sort network of swaps would do it.

Answer (score 3):

The function can look like

```
void sort_name(struct student *ptr) {
   int i,j=0;
   char temp[50];
   for ( i=0; i<3; i++ )
   {
       for (j = 1; j < 3 - i; j++ )
       {
           if(strcmp(ptr[j-1].name,ptr[j].name ) > 0 )
           {
               strcpy( temp, ptr[j-1].name );
               strcpy( ptr[j-1].name, ptr[j].name) ;
               strcpy( ptr[j].name, temp );
           }
       }
   }
}
```